# Simple silverlight sample does not show my data on datagrid

Tags: data-binding, datagridview, silverlight-4.0

I have a simple program which displays a collection on a data grid. When I run the code I do not see grid displaying data.  The model is

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public bool Sex;
}
```

The view model is

```
public class PeopleViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    List<Person> _personList;

    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        _personList = new List<Person>();
        _personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "n1", Age = 20, Sex = true });
        _personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "n2", Age = 20, Sex = true });
        _personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "n3", Age = 20, Sex = true });
        _personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "n4", Age = 20, Sex = true });
        _personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "n5", Age = 20, Sex = false });
    }

    public List<Person> PersonList
    {
        get { return _personList; }
        set { _personList = value; }
    }


    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The view xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <sdk:DataGrid Name="dataGrid1">
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

the code behind is

```
public PeopleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PeopleViewModel model = new PeopleViewModel();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = model.PersonList;
    }
```

Comment: two things you should think about changing... make your List an ObservableCollection, make your PersonList member use the PropertyChange

Comment: @Muad'Dib - you should have made your comment an answer...cus it's the only correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection I was binding was not public. That was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Should your DataGrid XAML contain `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`?
I'm comparing your code with this similar [detailed example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28VS.95%29.aspx).